# How to get authors avatar

Tags: avatar

How do I get the authors avatar? Buddypress plugin or any plugin.

I have found this inside my PHP code:

`"<i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>'.get_the_author().'</span></div>';"`

It shows a small image before the author's name, I wanted to change the `fa fa-user` into author's avatar or buddypress avatar.

What will be the script to do that?

Comment: if you want to make the icon inside author's avatar. you need a css to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The function you're looking for is [`get_avatar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) - you should put in something like this:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>
```

Comment: Hi there is an error it doesn't work. I substitute the code with the code you gave me, it shows error.

Comment: The function should output an `img` element. How did you use it exactly?

Comment: instead how do you put the buddypress avatar inside the div or i-tag?

Comment: I dont know if the buddypress avatar is fetched with the same function, I suppose it should. Did you try it like this?
<i><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?></i>

Comment: still error let me paste the whole code: $output .= '<div class="pl-detailcnt">';
            if($this->pw_grid_author=='no')
            {
             $output.=' 
              <div class="pl-postmeta" >
              <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>'.get_the_author().'</span></div>';
            }

Comment: Are you sure that all php code has the proper opening and ending tags? I suggest you start with only what I gave you just above and see if it does it, then work your way up from there.

Comment: Hi yes, I'm using the pw-vc-grid-list-post-layout plugin. still no luck

Comment: or instead how to use function code to add the avatar beside the code of get_the_author(), thankyou

Comment: Show output code for what I gave you above

Comment: I mean is there a shortcode that will be put in function.php that will show the avatar beside "get_the_author()"

Comment: hi I manage to show the avatar but it's too big the code i use is                                     <span>'.get_avatar( $author_id ).'</span><span>'.get_the_author().'</span></div>';

Comment: If it's too big, use css to style it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to get user avatar in WordPress.

**1st Method:**

```php
<?php
if (get_the_author_meta('email')) {
  echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('email'), '60');
}
?>
```

**2nd Method:**

```php
<?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>
```

**3rd Method**

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="<?php print get_avatar_url(get_current_user_id(), ['size' => '51']); ?>" media="(min-width: 992px)" />
  <img src="<?php print get_avatar_url(get_current_user_id(), ['size' => '40']); ?>" />
</picture>
```